# Authenticating into Wordpress from an Android WebView

Tags: android, wordpress, facebook, webview, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a hobby project that has 3 main components:

- an Android app,
- a Django-rest-framework based backend,
- a Wordpress frontend

The Android app authenticates against the REST API, and also supports logging in with Facebook.

There are some sections of the WP frontend I'd like to integrate by using an Android WebView, but some of the features in Wordpress require the user to be authenticated.

I initially thought of adding a user to the Wordpress user table whenever a new user registered through the backend, and then just authenticate using Wordpress' JSON API and inject the cookies into the WebView with JS. But this approach won't work when the user has registered through Facebook from Android (since there's no password I can use to authenticate through the JSON API).

So, in other words, I need to authenticate into Wordpress from an Android WebView, and support Facebook login and a custom authentication at the same time.

How can I deal with this scenario? Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication with username and password, you can use the REST API approach using JSON API. For Facebook Authentication,you can display the page with Facebook authentication on the WebView itself. Also use the same Cookie Store for both the WebView and the app. Read more: https://proandroiddev.com/a-tale-on-android-cookies-store-management-b04832ca18c6